# Wrong output while using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am trying to do a small program using threads that have 3 drinkers and each one will drink ONLY if he has the 3 things specified in the program

each one of them should start by having one of the 3 things

This is what I did so fare

```
import java.util.*;

import test.Producer.Consumer;

public class PC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AllResource c = new AllResource("water");
        AllResource c2 = new AllResource("ice");
        AllResource c3 = new AllResource("glass");
        Producer p1 = new Producer(c, 1);   // One Producer which acting  as Server

        Consumer c1   = new Consumer(c, 1);        // Consumer = Drinker(s)
        Consumer con2 = new Consumer(c2, 2);
        Consumer con3 = new Consumer(c3, 3);


        p1.start(); 
        p1 = new Producer(c2, 2);
        p1.start(); 
        p1=new Producer(c3, 3);
        c1.start();
        con2.start();
        con3.start();
        }
    }    
    class AllResource {
        private String resource;
        private boolean avail = false;
        ArrayList availableReource=new ArrayList();

        AllResource(String value){
            resource=value;        
        }       
        public boolean getAvail() {
               return avail;
        }
        public void setAvail(boolean avail1) {
               avail=avail1;
        }
        public synchronized String get(String value,boolean a, int number) {
            vail=a;

            if (avail == false) {
                resource=value;
                try {
                    wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            else {
                resource=value;
                avail = false;
                notifyAll();
            }
            return resource;
        }
        public String getResource() {
            return resource;
        }
        public synchronized void put(String value, boolean a) {       
            avail=a;
            if (avail == true) {
                resource=value;
                try {
                    wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) { 

                } 
            }
            else {
                resource = value;
                avail = true;
                notifyAll();
           }
        }
    }
    class Producer extends Thread {
        private AllResource allResource;
        private int number;
        String resource[]={"water", "ice", "glass"};
        ArrayList al=new ArrayList();

        public Producer(AllResource c, int number) {
            allResource = c;
            this.number = number;
            al.add(c.getResource());
        }   
        public void run() {         
            while(true) {
                int rand=0;
                for(int j=0;j<resource.length;j++) {
                    rand=(int)(Math.random() * 3);
                    if(allResource.getResource()==(resource[rand])) {
                        allResource.put("",true);
                    }
                    else {
                        allResource.put(resource[rand],false); 
                    }   
                    System.out.println("Server #" + " put: "
                    + resource[rand] + " for Drinker "+this.number);   
                } 
            }
        }
        class Consumer extends Thread {
            private AllResource allResource;
            private int number;
            String resource[]={"water", "ice", "glass"};

            public Consumer(AllResource c, int number) {
                allResource = c;
                this.number = number;
            }
            public void run() {  
                while(true) {
                    for(int j=0;j<resource.length;j++) {
                        if(allResource.getResource().equals(resource[j])) {
                            allResource.get("",false,this.number);
                        }    
                        else {
                            allResource.get((String)resource[j],true,this.number);
                        }
                        System.out.println("Drinker  #" + this.number + " received: " + resource[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }      
    }
```

I am getting a wrong output for some reason
Here is part of the output

```
Server # put: glass for Drinker 1
Drinker  #3 received: water // drinker #3 received water even though there is no water provided for anyone
Drinker  #3 received: ice // drinker 3 received ice even though there is no ice provided for anyone
Server # put: ice for Drinker 2  
Drinker  #2 received: water // drinker 2 should receive ice not water
Server # put: glass for Drinker 2
Drinker  #3 received: glass // drinker 2 should receive glass not drinker 3 !
Server # put: glass for Drinker 1
Drinker  #1 received: water // it should receive glass not water
Server # put: ice for Drinker 1

// and now it's receiving lots of things and the server is not providing anything for him !
Drinker  #3 received: water
Drinker  #3 received: ice
Drinker  #3 received: glass
Drinker  #3 received: water

// same thing
Server # put: water for Drinker 2
Drinker  #2 received: ice
Drinker  #3 received: ice
Drinker  #1 received: ice
```

Can someone help me with this ? I don't know why am I getting these kinds of logical errors

Comment: You posted quite a long block of code, and it's not even indented. Analyzing someone else's multi-threded code when the code is not even indented is not an easy task.

Comment: Do be aware that, when using System.out, output from different threads may not appear in the "correct" order.

Comment: synchronize part where you are printing out reseived resources and see what happen than

Comment: I dont wanna be picky, but person who is doing Concurrency should know  basic Java principles ... class name CAPITALIZED, and variable names should be a meaningful word  + format your code please ...

Comment: @HotLicks I actually want it to be done randomly but I don't want them to be wrong. I don't care which one will drink first but I don't want it to be this way.

Comment: @MaciejCygan it doesn't matter in java if the class name is capital or not !
but I will format it anyway

Comment: @JBNizet I've edited the post. Please let me know if this is not good enough.

Comment: @rullzrullz Capitalizing Java class name is part of the Naming convention, so it does make a difference :).

Comment: OK @MaciejCygan  it's capital now.

Comment: My point is that output in System.out may not appear in the order that the events actually occurred.

Comment: @HotLicks so how am I suppose to fix this problem ?

Comment: Just be aware of it.  The output should eventually come out.  You can "force" the output various ways, but at the expense of slowing things and possibly upsetting your threading sequence.  (You could of course output a synchronized counter with each message, to allow you to identify the order, though maintaining the counter would have some small effect.

Comment: The code is still not indented correctly. Every IDE out these can indent a whole class with a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @JBNizet it should be okay now. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've not analyzed the code completely, but the following is enough to explain the first "errors" you get:

```
String resource[]={"water", "ice", "glass"};

public void run() {  
    while(true) {
        for (int j = 0; j < resource.length; j++) {
            // removed irrelevant code   
            System.out.println("Drinker  #" + this.number + " received: " + resource[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

So, you're not printing what a drinker receives. You're printing every element of an array containing all three resources.

Another problem I've seen at first glance is that you're not respecting the idiom that is mandated in the javadoc of `Object.wait()`, which should always be called in a loop.

You should not use `wait()` and `notifyAll()`, which are complex, very low-level methods. Use higher-level concurrent objects from the java.util.concurrent package, like `BlockingQueue`, which are easy to use a well suited for producer/consumer problems.

Comment: Thank you. I've removed the if statements in both run functions but I still have a wrong output. I want to use wait() and notifyAll() this is why I didn't use something else